# How to rotate a sprite around the origin of another sprite in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

In my game i have sprite1 and sprite2. Sprite1 has a center origin. I want sprite2 to use the origin of sprite1. But both sprites don't align properly.
here is my code:

```
sprite1.setRegion(AssetLoader.rocket);
    sprite1.setPosition(rocket.getX(), rocket.getY());
    sprite1.setOrigin(rocket.getWidth() / 2, rocket.getHeight() / 2);
    sprite1.setSize(rocket.getWidth(), rocket.getHeight());
    sprite1.setRotation(rocket.getRotation());
    sprite1.setScale(1, 1);
    sprite1.draw(game.batch);

    int w = 70;
    int h = 20;
    float x = escapePod.getX() + escapePod.getWidth() / 2 - w / 2;
    float y = escapePod.getY() + escapePod.getHeight() / 2 - h / 2 - (escapePod.getHeight() + 4);
    sprite2.setRegion(AssetLoader.flame);
    sprite2.setPosition(x, y);
    sprite2.setOrigin(sprite1.getOriginX(), sprite1.getOriginY());
    sprite2.setSize(w, h);
    sprite2.setRotation(rocket.getRotation());
    sprite2.setScale(1, 1);
    sprite2.draw(game.batch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the center of your sprite and the another sprite. You can calculate the distance between them. Once you have it and the angle of the rotation, you rotate your sprite and you calculate the position of the another sprite. If its in the right position you rotate the another sprite by the negative value of your angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what should i put in the setOrigin parameters of sprite2?

Comment: @Harry Banda Oh i see, well maybe the easiest way you can do it is something like 
x = x * cos (angle) - y * sin(angle) , y = x * sin(angle) - y * cos (angle) where x and y are coordinates of the center of your sprite and angle is the angle of the rotation.